# TFS 2012 Build Definition/Template - How to set Build Quality Automatically?

Tags: tfs, build, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I thought this would be pretty straight forward, but it looks like the template has to be modified.  Anyone have any idea what to do to add this piece to the default template?

I know how to edit the templates, I just don't know what I need to do to make this work.

Comment: Why do you want to set the build quality automatically as part of a build? You don't know anything about the build quality at that point, other than compilation was successful/unsuccessful and whether unit tests passed.

Comment: I will set it to released if everything passes.  I can do checks during the build to handle all of that.  I just have no idea how to set that part.  It makes little sense to automate a build, but have the build manager set every build quality for every build by hand.  That's just nuts.  The build can figure out what the quality is by how far it gets.

Answer (score 0):

[This case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/030a9cc7-4c91-4132-a9fa-0fbcf119218d/tfs2010-team-build-automatically-update-build-quality?forum=tfsbuild) already provided a solution for your requirement:

1. Copy the DefaultTemplate.xaml to DefaultTemplateCustom.xaml and open it
2. Click the Collapse All link in the top right corner
3. Open the toolbox and locate the **Assign** activity. It is located in the **Primitives** section
4. Drag the **Assign** activity to the end of the workflow, after the "Run MSBuild" activity
5. Go to the properties window. Set the "**To**" parameter to **BuildDetail.Quality**. Set "**Value**" to "***xxx (Build Quality)***"
6. Locate the **InvokeMethod** in the toolbox and drag it and drop it after the **Assign** activity
7. Set the "**Target Object**" to **BuildDetail**. Set "**MethodName**" to **Save**
8. Save the build definition xaml file and check it in, then build with the customized definition.

Comment: I already tried that. The Assign Activity does not allow you to set strings directly into this property: Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildDetail.Quality".Invalid L-value expression.:Reference expressions cannot end with Conversion. The provided expression's type must exactly match the type T of VisualBasicReference<T> or LambdaReference<T>.

Comment: There are errors in your build template, you need to check the error in the template and correct it. Assuming you got 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildDetail' is not accessible error, then check the solution in this case https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49f11ed9-9fa8-4c20-952a-d39ee7e71051/can-no-longer-user-builddetaildroplocation-for-copydirectory-with-tfs-2013-using-build-process?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: I've tested the solution in TfvcTemplate.12.xaml (I don't have TFS 2012 Build Definition any more), and move the Assign activity and  InvokeMethod activity after "Run MSBuild" step, then got a successful result.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider to create a powershell script to set the build quality via TFS API and then invoke this powershell script in your build template. Refer to this link for details: [PowerShell and TFS: The Basics and Beyond](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/21/powershell-and-tfs-the-basics-and-beyond/).

Here is a simple script to set the build quality:

```
$builduri = "vstfs:///Build/Build/1";
$collectionurl = "http://xxxx:8080/tfs/xxx/";
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($collectionurl);
$buildservice = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer]);
$build = $buildservice.GetBuild($builduri);
$build.Quality = "Released";
$build.Save()
```